# React JS - render data from Open AQ API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, typeerror, fetch-api

I'm trying to do the app which shows 10 most polluted cities from chosen country, using data from [Open AQ](https://docs.openaq.org/). However, I get error which says:

> TypeError: this.props.cities.map is not a function

and I don't know how I should fix it. I'm posting the whole code, because you may find some mistake in place, that I even didn't consider.

This is my App file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Input from './components/Input';
import CitiesList from './components/CitiesList';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countryCode: '',
      cities: []
    };
    this.onCountryChange = this.onCountryChange.bind(this);
    this.airQuality = this.airQuality.bind(this);
  }

  onCountryChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      countryCode: event.target.value
    })
  };

  airQuality = () => {
    const URL = 'https://api.openaq.org/v1/measurements?country=${countryCode}&limit=10&order_by=value&sort=desc';

    fetch(URL) 
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        }
        throw Error(response.status)
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          cities: data.results
        })
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Input onChange={this.onCountryChange}/>
        <CitiesList cities={this.airQuality}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Input file:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const countries = [
    {country: 'Poland', value: 'PL'},
    {country: 'Germany', value: 'DE'},
    {country: 'Spain', value: 'ES'},
    {country: 'France', value: 'FR'}
]

class Input extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Autocomplete
            id="combo-box"
            options={countries}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.country}
            style={{ width: 300, marginTop: 10 }}
            renderInput={params => (
              <TextField {...params} label="Type a country" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
            )}
          />
        )
    }
}

export default Input;
```

and `CitiesList` where I get the error:

```
import React from 'react';

class CitiesList extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const items = this.props.cities.map((city, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <h2>{city.name}</h2>
                <p>
                    <div>
                        Parameter: {city.parameter}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Value: {city.value} {city.unit}
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
        ));
        return (
            <div>
                {items}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default CitiesList;
```

I will appreciate your help.

---

Edit:
Akshit Mehra and Roman Unt helped me a lot and I resolved two issues in my code however there are still some mistakes. It still doesn't show cities when I select the country and I see, it's because `countryCode` doesn't update. The function `onCountryChange` didn't even fire and I realised it's because `onChange` event handler should be in input tag and I put it in component named Input. So I moved it to `Autocomplete` component and now I have:

In `App.js`

```
<Input onCountryChange={this.onCountryChange}/>
```

and in `Input.js`

```
const Input = ({onCountryChange}) => (
    <Autocomplete
    id="combo-box"
    options={countries}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.country}
    style={{ width: 300, marginTop: 10 }}
    onChange={onCountryChange}
    renderInput={params => (
      <TextField {...params} label="Type a country" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
    )}
    />
)
```

Now I see in console that function `onCountryChange` fires, however it still doesn't update `countryCode` (this.state.countryCode is 0).

Could you please help?

Comment: <CitiesList cities={this.airQuality}/> why do you pass fetching method here? Instead of passing state with fetched cities?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `airQuality` into your `<CitiesList cities={this.airQuality} />` component, which is a method and not an iterable array. This method is updating the `cities` state and you should use the `.map()` function on `cities` array.

Instead, pass the `cities` state as `props`, as such `<CitiesList cities={this.state.cities} />`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it helped, now I don't have the error. However it still doesn't work, I mean, when I select the country, it doesn't show cities. Maybe I understand it uncorrectly, but I think I should somehow put airQuality in render method (but how?), because now it seems like the app doesn't use this method.

Comment: You can call the `this.airQuality()` method in the `componentDidMount()` and/or `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle hook(s), as required. All calls to fetch data from API(s) should be made from these lifecycle hooks.

Comment: Thank you, it helped, but there is still something wrong. I wrote it as edit of question.

Answer (score 0):

I did several corrections and now it renders data.

1. I changed `onCountryChange` function. Now I have in Input.js:

```
const countries = [
    {country: 'Poland', code: 'PL'},
    {country: 'Germany', code: 'DE'},
    {country: 'Spain', code: 'ES'},
    {country: 'France', code: 'FR'}
]
```

and in App.js:

```
onCountryChange = (object, value) => {
    this.setState({
      countryCode: value.code
    });

  };
```

and in render method:

```
const { countryCode } = this.state;
```

2. In `const URL` I changed quotes to backticks and `countryCode` to `this.state.countryCode`
3. I changed `componentDidMount` to `componentDidUpdate`

I still have to improve it, because I see in console, that airQuality function keeps going over and over and it doesn't stop after it renders 10 elements and also, it doesn't show city name, but only parameter, value and unit, but I'm one step further :)